# Running PY file outside of Spyder

Tags: spyder

I used to be able to double click .py file and it would proivde me CMD prompt to run the script. 
At the moment I have to go into Spyder each time to run the file.

What do I need to do to be able to run outside of Spyder?

Thanks

Comment: Right-click your Python script, and go to properties. In "General", select "opens with" and point it to your Python executable.

Comment: Or, open PowerShell or something, and type `py myscript.py`. This is a typical alias on Windows machines.

Answer (score -1):

open a terminal/cmd in the directory the file is in and then write `python pythonFile.py`

**EDIT**

alternative option, open Powershell in the directory the file is in or open powershell and navigate to the directory the file is in and use this command to source a document in the current directory `./test.py`

Comment: PS C:\Users\david\Documents\Python> python AXIS Scraper.py
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python AXIS Scraper.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\david\Documents\Python>

Comment: @troy is python added you your windows PATH? its a tick box on python installer wizard, or to manually install: [HERE](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

Comment: @troy i just tried a script of my own, opening power shell in the directory and something like `./test.py` sources the file as expected

Comment: PS C:\Users\david\Documents\Python> python axis scraper.py
C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'axis': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\david\Documents\Python>

Comment: when i rename it to just axis. I get the following below:

PS C:\Users\david\Documents\Python> python axis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "axis.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api, win32con, win32gui, win32ui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
PS C:\Users\david\Documents\Python>

Comment: @troy if one of my answers solved your issue could you please mark the answer as such?